# Best way to add php variable within shortcode

Tags: php

So I have a php variable: `$site= $your_name->getName("dfd_Name");`

I have the following shortcode: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_site dfd_Name=" "]'); ?>`

What is the best way to put the `$site` variable into the `dfd_Name=" "` ? (something like `dfd_Name="$site"`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_site dfd_Name="'.$site.'"]'); ?>
```

Which in a neat form would look like this

```
<?php
  echo do_shortcode( '[my_site dfd_Name="'. $site .'"]' );
?>
```

It can also be

```
<?= do_shortcode( '[my_site dfd_Name="'. $site .'"]' ); ?>
```

It can also be

```
<?php
 $sc= '[my_site dfd_Name="'. $your_name->getName("dfd_Name") .'"]';
 echo do_shortcode($sc);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way would be with short tag:

```
<?= do_shortcode('[my_site dfd_Name="'.$site.'"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one you can check :

```
<?php
    echo do_shortcode('[my_site dfd_Name="' . $site . '"]');
?>
```